# On Convolution: Show that $g_a *g_b = g_{\min(a,b)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

For $a>0$, I have been given following  the functions 
$$f_a(x)=\frac{a}{π(x^2+a^2)}$$
 and 
$$g_a(x)=\frac{\sin(ax)}{π x}~~x\neq0,\qquad g_a(0)= \frac{a}{π}. $$

**Question** Show that,

$$f_a *f_b =  f_{a+b}$$
and $$g_a *g_b =  g_{\min(a,b)}$$

I was able to prove that $f_a *f_b =  f_{a+b}$ through Fourier Transform.

Can anyone help to show that $g_a *g_b =  g_{\min(a,b)}$ or any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fourier transform too:
$$\mathcal F(g_a*g_b)=\mathcal F(g_a)\mathcal F(g_b).$$
Up to normalisation factors, $\mathcal F(g_a)$ is the indicator
function of the interval $[-a,a]$, so it is apparent that
$$\mathcal F(g_a)\mathcal F(g_b)=\mathcal F(g_{\min(a,b)})$$
etc.